# how to set a max fps in java

Tags: java, frame-rate

I was making a 2D game, and I realized that the FPS was around 500, but it kept dropping to 440 and that  made horrible lag spikes so I wanted to set a max fps to stop the lag spikes, but I don't know how to do that. Game loop:

```
    public void run(){
    this.requestFocus();
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
    double ns = 1000000000/amountOfTicks;
    double delta = 0;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int frames = 0;
    while(running){
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;
        while(delta >= 1){
            tick();
            delta--;
        }
        if(running)
            render();
    frames++;

    if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000){
        timer += 1000;
        System.out.println("FPS: " + frames);
        frames = 0;
        }
    }
    stop();
}
```

Comment: How can 440 frames per second be a lag spike? Your eyes can even distinguish frames at that rate. Remember, the movement speed of you graphics should be independent of the frame rate. Whether you get 10 fps or 500 fps, the overall speed of objects should remain the same, e.g. take the same real-time to move from left border to right border.

Comment: They do move the same, but the sudden frame drops make the game chop a little

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the same control mechanism you used to control the number of ticks. Try this, and put the max FPS you desire in the 'amountOfRenders' variable.

```
public void run(){
    this.requestFocus();
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
    double ns = 1000000000/amountOfTicks;
    double delta = 0;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int frames = 0;
    int ticks = 0;

    long renderLastTime=System.nanoTime();
    double amtOfRenders = 200.0;//MAX FPS
    double renderNs=1000000000/amtOfRenders;
    double renderDelta = 0;

    while(running){
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;
        while(delta >= 1){
            tick();
            ticks++;
            delta--;
        }

        now = System.nanoTime();
        renderDelta += (now - renderLastTime) / renderNs;
        renderLastTime = now;
        while(running && renderDelta >= 1){
            render();
            frames++;
            renderDelta--;
        }

        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000){
            timer += 1000;
            System.out.println("FPS: " + frames);
            System.out.println("Ticks per second: " + ticks);
            frames = 0;
            ticks = 0;
        }
    }
    stop();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! My game is a lot smoother now!